# Chromecast sending custom data ios

Tags: android, ios, chromecast, drm

In iOS there is this API to send customData

```
NSDictionary *customData = @{@"key": @"value"}
  GCKMediaInformation *mediaInformation = [[GCKMediaInformation alloc] initWithContentID:[url absoluteString]
                                                                                streamType:streamType
                                                                               contentType:@"movie"
                                                                                  metadata:metadata
                                                                            streamDuration:self.currentMedia.duration
                                                                            customData:customData];
```

The problem here is customData is of type id and I can only pass it as NSDictionary or a JSON String.

```
MediaInfo mediaInfo =  mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder(
                    resolvedUrl)
                    .setContentType("movie")
                    .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
                    .setMetadata(mediaMetadata)
                    .setCustomData(program.getJSONObject())
                    .build();
```

Declared as following in the chromecast API

```
public MediaInfo.Builder setCustomData(JSONObject customData)
```

But on Android the same API is the customData is of JSONObject which works fine like this.

On iOS doing this is not possible so how to send customData as JSONObject in iOS

Comment: Can't you just do a jsonObject.toString() to get a string version of that, send it over the channel and on the receiver get back a string that can be changed to a json object trivially?

Comment: By the way, if I understand your question correctly, you have the dictionary and you want to pass it to the parameter which takes (id type). If I am correct, then You can pass any type of data, because in iOS "id" type can take any type of parameter.
So you can pass dictionary, or json string to the customData.